# LuaJava - unprotected error in call to Lua API

Tags: java, eclipse, lua, luajava

I'm trying to get a simple function working in LuaJava (adding two numbers). I have very little experience with Lua, and am finding this difficult as I haven't been able to find in depth documentation for LuaJava. I can currently print out to the java console from lua, but nothing beyond that.

I have tried implementing a few methods, but get the same error every time:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaState;
import org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaStateFactory;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LuaState l = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
        l.openLibs();
        l.LdoFile("main.lua");
        l.call(0, 0);
        l.getGlobal("add");
        l.pushInteger(1);
        l.pushInteger(1);
        l.call(2, 1);
        int result = l.toInteger(1);
        l.pop(1);
        System.out.println("1 + 1 = " + result); 
    }
}
```

And the Lua file:

```
function add(a, b) 
    return a + b
end
```

My IDE is Eclipse. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume the problem is occurring on this line `l.call(0, 0);`.

`l.LdoFile("main.lua");` does not, most likely, return a function on the stack that must be called. That is what the lua C function `luaL_loadfile` does. `luaL_dofile` is a macro around `luaL_loadfile` which *also* runs the returned chunk function.

So after `l.LdoFile("main.lua");` finishes I believe you have nothing on the stack and your `add` function is available for use.

Comment: Thanks. Got rid of that line and it's working now. I had to change the l.pushInteger calls to l.pushNumber as well for some reason. Thanks again for the help!